# How can I use another window manager, such as Kwin, in place of Gala?

Tags: startup, window-manager, cerbere

If I want to use another window manager by default, what process would I need to go through to achieve this?

I would like it to work along with cerbere.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is untested but will probably work. If it doesn't I'll check why.

Adapting the base session startup programs may already be enough, those are found in `/usr/share/gnome-session/sessions/pantheon.session`. Replace gala with the appropriate process name.

Looking at cerbere's monitored processes list, it looks like it's currently not restarting the WM. If you want to change that, you have to add it at `org.pantheon.cerbere.monitored-processes`.